# Largest element of matrix, template function c++

Tags: c++

I have to write a template function which finds the largest element of matrix. I tried this and error is:
`Error 1 error C2664: 'greatest' :
 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [3][3]' to 'int [][1]'`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
T greatest(T a[][],int n, int m){
    T max = a[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            if(a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
    return max;
}

int main(){
    int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int max = greatest<int>(a,3,3);
    cout << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `**a` instead of `a[][]`.

Comment: @OlegVaskevich

I tried, but if first argument of function is **a, how to define variable in main that will be matrix and of type **a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the length of the last array like this:

```
template<class T>
T greatest(T a[][3], int n, int m);
```

Improved version (compiler can deduce it for us):

```
template<class T, int N>
T greatest(T a[][N], int n, int m); // The function call doesn't change
```

Edit:

Even more improved version, which doesn't require length parameters:

```
template<class T, int N, int M>
T greatest(T (&a)[N][M]);
```

Comment: But with `template<class T, int N>` function is returning some address, not the biggest int.

Comment: There is a slight mistake in your code: It should be `cout << max << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

Why pass the dimensions explicitly when you are writing a template? Just make them template parameters and let the compiler deduce it. You'll need to take the array by reference to prevent array-to-pointer decay.

```
template<class T, int N, int M>
T greatest(T (&a)[N][M]){
    T max = a[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
            if(a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
    return max;
}
```

and you don't need to specify `T` explicitly when calling `greatest` either.

```
int max = greatest(a);
```